# Apex Continuation - Response Method

Tags: apex, visualforce, callout, asynchronous

I am using Apex Continuation to make a callout from a VF page, but the response method is not being executed and, as a result, no response is displayed on the page. Can anyone please see why this is failing? I am re-rendering the outer output panel following the button click, which SHOULD display the `{!Result}`, but it doesn't seem to be executing the response method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Controller Extension:

```
   public class TakePaymentControllerExtension {

    public Opportunity theOpp {get;set;}
    public Id theOppId {get;set;}
    public Booking__c booking {get;set;}

    public String requestLabel {get;set;}
    public String result {get;set;}
    public String errorMessage {get;set;}
    //State variable for rendering output panels
    public Double finalAmount {get;set;}
    public Boolean showLoading {get;set;}
    public Boolean showError {get;set;}
    public Boolean showResults {get;set;}
    public Boolean showForm {get;set;}

    //List (and Class Name) for logging exceptions/errors
    List<Error_Log__c> logs = new List<Error_Log__c>();
    String CLASS_NAME = 'TakePaymentControllerExtension';  

    public TakePaymentControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController cont){

        //Hide loading spinner (Default)
        showLoading = false;
        //Hide Errors (Default)
        showError = false;
        //Hide Results (Default)
        showResults = false;
        //Show the form
        showForm = true;

        //Retrieve the Opportunity
        theOppId = cont.getRecord().Id;

        //Retrieve the Opp and related booking
        theOpp = [Select Id, Name, Transaction_Authorised_Amount__c, Card_Token_Id__c, (Select Id,  Account__c, Account__r.PersonEmail From Bookings__r Order by LastModifiedDate Desc LIMIT 1) From Opportunity Where Id = :theOppId];
        if(theOpp != null){
            system.debug('theOpp: '+theOpp);
            if(theOpp.Bookings__r != null && theOpp.Bookings__r.size()>0){ 
                booking = theOpp.Bookings__r[0];
                system.debug('booking: '+booking);
            }else{
                //Display No Booking error
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No Booking was found for this Opportunity ('+theOpp.Name+' ['+theOpp.Id+']). Please contact your system administrator for assistance'));
                showError = true;
                return;
            }
        }else{
            //Display No Opportunity error
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'No Opportunity record was found. Please contact your system administrator for assistance'));
            showError = true;
            return;
        }


        //Check all the required information is available
        boolean verified = verifyPaymentRequestDetails();
        if(verified != null && !verified){
            //TO DO -- Display Validation (errorMessage)
            //APEX PAGES ERROR
            showError = true;
        }

        //Default finalAmount
        finalAmount = theOpp.Transaction_Authorised_Amount__c;

    }

    //This method handles the payment request to Clubhouse    
    public Object processRequest(){

        //Validation to ensure the final amount does not exceed the authorised transaction amount
        if(theOpp.Transaction_Authorised_Amount__c < finalAmount){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'The payment cannot exceed the "Transaction Authorised Amount": '+theOpp.Transaction_Authorised_Amount__c ));
            showError = true;
            showForm = true;
            return null;
        }else{

            //Hide Error, Hide Form, Show Spinner
            showError = false;     
            showForm = false;   
            showLoading = true;

            //Build Booking Payment Request wrapper
            system.debug('Building Payment Request Wrapper');

            ... (Built wrapper: bprw)

            try{

                // Create callout request
                Http http = new Http();                
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                request.setMethod('POST');
                request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                request.setEndpoint('callout:APICredentials/api/Payment');
                request.setBody(JSON.serialize(bprw));
                system.debug('Request Body: '+request.getBody());

                //Get timeout value from custom setting
                Http_Timeout__c httpTimeout = Http_Timeout__c.getInstance('Take Payment');
                Integer timeOut;            
                if (null != httpTimeout){
                    //We have a value, so set the timeout
                    system.debug('*** -- Setting Take Payment timeout to ' + integer.valueOf(httpTimeout.Timeout_In_Seconds__c) + ' -- ***');
                    timeOut = integer.valueOf(httpTimeout.Timeout_In_Seconds__c);
                }else{
                    //Else it will keep the default of 20 seconds
                    timeOut = 20;
                }

                system.debug('Time Out: '+timeOut);

                // Create continuation with a timeout
                Continuation con = new Continuation(timeOut);
                // Set callback method
                con.continuationMethod='processResponse';

                // Add callout request to continuation
                requestLabel = con.addHttpRequest(request);
                system.debug('Request Label: '+requestLabel);

                // Return the continuation
                return con;  


            }catch(exception e){
                //DISPLAY ERROR
                system.debug('Contination Apex Error: '+e);
                return null;                  
            }
        }

    }

    // Callback method 
    public Object processResponse() {   
        system.debug('Processing Response');
        //Hide the loading spinner
        showLoading = false;
        showResults = true;
        showForm = false;

        // Get the response by using the unique label
        HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(this.requestLabel);
        // Set the result variable that is displayed on the Visualforce page
        this.result = response.getBody();
        system.debug('Response Body: '+result);

        // Return null to re-render the original Visualforce page
        return null;
    }    


}
```

VF PAGE:

```
  <apex:page StandardController="Opportunity" extensions="TakePaymentControllerExtension" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" lightningStylesheets="true">    
    <apex:form>  
        <apex:outputPanel id="theForm">
            <div class="slds-scope slds-p-around_medium">  
                <apex:slds />
                <div class="slds-p-around_large">
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showError}">
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters">
                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <div id="PageErrors" class="slds-page-header" style="background: rgb(180, 0, 0); color:rgb(255,255,255);">
                                    <apex:messages />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters">
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <div id="Page Header" class="slds-page-header" style="border-left: 4px solid rgb(176, 214, 48);">
                                Take Payment - {!theOpp.Name}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>         
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showForm}">                
                        <div id="MainBody" class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters">
                            <div id="Column1" class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-around_medium">
                                <div class="slds-box" style="min-height:200px; background:white;">
                                    <h1 class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-p-around_medium" >
                                        Confirm Payment Amount
                                    </h1> 
                                    <div class="slds-form-element">
                                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                            <apex:inputText value="{!finalAmount}" styleClass="slds-input slds-align_absolute-center" style="width:50%;"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>                            
                            </div>
                            <div id="Column2" class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-around_medium">
                                <div class="slds-box" style="min-height:200px; background:white;">                        
                                    <h1 class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-p-around_medium">
                                        Transaction Authorised Amount
                                    </h1>
                                    <apex:outputText value="{0, number, currency}" styleClass="slds-align_absolute-center">
                                        <apex:param value="{!theOpp.Transaction_Authorised_Amount__c}"/>
                                    </apex:outputText>                            
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div id="Footer" class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters">
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">
                                <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-p-horizontal_large slds-size_12-of-12 slds-box " action="{!processRequest}" value="Take Payment" reRender="theForm"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <div>
                        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showLoading}">
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                                <div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">
                                    <div id="spinner" class="slds-spinner_container slds-is-relative slds-align_absolute-center" >
                                        <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner--large slds-spinner--brand">
                                            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                                            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                            
                            </div>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters">
                            <apex:outputPanel id="Results" rendered="{!showResults}">
                                <apex:outputText value="{!result}"/> 
                                RESULTS
                            </apex:outputPanel>                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>              
            </div> 
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

DEBUG LOG 1 - Initial REQUEST

> 42.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,NONE;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,NONE;WAVE,NONE;WORKFLOW,ERROR
>   22:53:00.0 (345875)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005b0000004IcX6|jradcliffe@example.com|Greenwich Mean Time|GMT+01:00
>   22:53:00.0 (395909)|EXECUTION_STARTED
>   22:53:00.0 (403790)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|0667E000000G8eK|VF: /apex/TakePaymentVF
>   22:53:00.0 (15338870)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (15852265)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (16124677)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (31413522)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (31614836)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (34549099)|USER_DEBUG|[104]|DEBUG|Building Payment Request Wrapper
>   22:53:00.0 (47141418)|USER_DEBUG|[139]|DEBUG|Request Body: {"PaymentMethods":[{"TokenisedCardPayment":{"Surcharge":{"Value":0.0,"CurrencyIso3Code":"GBP"},"EmailAddress":"fakeClient@example.com","ClientAccountID":"0017E00000ouXRWQA2","CardName":null},"SalesforceTrackingID":"0067E00000AHgPvQAL","Amount":{"Value":12.2,"CurrencyIso3Code":"GBP"}}],"BookingSalesforceID":"a0Y7E0000032r9aUAA","BookingGolfbreaksID":23432}
>   22:53:00.0 (49119613)|USER_DEBUG|[146]|DEBUG|*** -- Setting Take Payment timeout to 10 -- ***
>   22:53:00.0 (49178518)|USER_DEBUG|[153]|DEBUG|Time Out: 10
>   22:53:00.0 (50842887)|USER_DEBUG|[162]|DEBUG|Request Label: Continuation-1
>   22:53:00.0 (52163973)|USER_DEBUG|[EXTERNAL]|DEBUG|Continuation Controllers State: 1807 out of 81920 bytes used (0.02%), count 2
>   22:53:00.0 (128716393)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (129105529)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (129490462)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/TakePaymentVF
>   22:53:00.0 (131184285)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

DEBUG LOG 2 - Response

> 42.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,NONE;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,NONE;WAVE,NONE;WORKFLOW,ERROR
>   22:53:00.0 (80384)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005b0000004IcX6|jradcliffe@example.com|Greenwich Mean Time|GMT+01:00
>   22:53:00.0 (155506)|EXECUTION_STARTED
>   22:53:00.0 (162964)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|0667E000000G8eK|VF: /apex/TakePaymentVF
>   22:53:00.0 (5561870)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (5765586)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (5906050)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (6103491)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   22:53:00.0 (60845798)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/TakePaymentVF
>   22:53:00.0 (62454319)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

Comment: Please make sure to use the `{}` Code Formatting button or Ctrl-K to format your code; otherwise it is mangled or not shown.

Comment: Apologies, first ever question on the exchange. I have edited the code format ^^^ Thanks

Comment: Is your request method getting called, and can you debug continuation object to see if values are present?

Comment: Hi Pranay. I have added the logs above ^^^. The method is getting called and a few moments later a second log is recorded, but it does not have much content. It seems an asynchronous transaction is launched, but if the response method was run, I would expect to see the response body in the logs. Thanks